# grunt-contrib-uglify doesn't minify the object property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gruntjs, minify, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'd like to minify my JS code using Grunt's grunt-contrib-uglify package. My project's JS file looks like this:

```
// src/js/script.js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "...",
  data: {...},
  computed: {...},
  methods: {...},
  beforeMount() {...} // line 902
});
```

Although the un-minified code works fine, Uglify throws an error when it hits line 902. I'm guessing it's because the way beforeMount() is declared isn't standard JavaScript. If I remove it, script.js is minified no problem. Unfortunately, it's crucial to the project, and I can't think of another workaround.

I've tried using `grunt --force`, but it doesn't output anything.

I'd be interested in thoughts on getting Grunt to minify this, or alternatives to Grunt that do the same job. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost right. The syntax of `beforeMount()` is the declaration of class method (es6), but this is an object property.

You should use this syntax:

```
beforeMount: function() {...}
```